# settings are not displayed in the applications in Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I downloaded the applications from the application center, but the settings are not displayed in the downloaded application, that is, there is a settings button, but when you click on it, a white window appears. And if you click on this window, the application does not respond.

Comment: The same problem was in the previous version (22.04)